# How to generate all weeks between two week numbers of same/different year?

Tags: scala

In my application, a week is represented as a String with format:

```
{year}-{week-no} // week-no ranges from 1 to 52
```

For eg: *7th week of year 2017 is represented as: `2017-07`*

I want to write a method that takes two week dates and generate all weeks in between those two given weeks. So, if I pass:

- `2017-05` and `2017-08` *(same years)* : The method should return `List(2017-05,2017-06,2017-07,2017-08)`
- `2017-05` and `2019-02` *(different years)* : The method should return `List(2017-05,2017-06,.........2017-51,2017-52,2018-01,2018-02,.......2018-51,2018-52,2019-01,2019-02)`

I have developed the following solution so far which works:

```
def weeksGenerator(fromWeek: String,toWeek: String): List[String] = {
    val upperWeekNummber = fromWeek.split("-").toList.last.toInt
    val upperYearNummber = fromWeek.split("-").toList.head.toInt
    val lowerWeekNummber = toWeek.split("-").toList.last.toInt
    val lowerYearNummber = toWeek.split("-").toList.head.toInt

    (lowerYearNummber - upperYearNummber) match {
      case 0L => Range.inclusive(upperWeekNummber,lowerWeekNummber).map{weekNum =>
        s"${upperYearNummber.toString}-${weekNum}"
      }.toList
      case diff: Int =>
        Range.inclusive(0,diff).foreach(println)
        Range.inclusive(0,diff).flatMap{
        d => if(d==diff){
          // this is the last element
          Range.inclusive(1,lowerWeekNummber).map{weekNum =>
            s"${(upperYearNummber+d).toString}-${weekNum}"
          }
        }
        else if(d ==0) {
          // first element
          Range.inclusive(upperWeekNummber,52).map{weekNum =>
            s"${(upperYearNummber+d).toString}-${weekNum}"
          }
        }
        else {
          Range.inclusive(1,52).map{weekNum =>
            s"${(upperYearNummber+d).toString}-${weekNum}"
          }
        }
      }.toList
    }
  }
```

I think there are two problems with my solution:

- I don't think it is the most `concise and functional` solution.
- When the week numbers are from `1 to 9`, I would like to generate `2017-01`, `2017-02` instead of `2017-1`, `2017-2`. I don't want to manually append 0. I am looking for a better approach.

So, what would be the best approach here ?

Comment: Depending on your use case you might have to take leap weeks into account https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date this will complicate the solution a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably do the following:

```
def weeksGenerator(fromWeek: String,toWeek: String): List[String] = {
  val maxWeeks = 52
  val minWeeks = 1

  val year1 = fromWeek.split("-")(0).toInt
  val year2 = toWeek.split("-")(0).toInt
  val week1 = fromWeek.split("-")(1).toInt
  val week2 = toWeek.split("-")(1).toInt

  val wholeWeeks = minWeeks to maxWeeks
  val years = year1 to year2
  val headWeeks = week1 to maxWeeks
  val lastWeeks = minWeeks to week2

  val enumeratedYears = years.zip(1 to years.length)
  val yearsAndWeeksZip = enumeratedYears.map{case (year, index) => if (index == 1) (year, headWeeks) else if (index == years.length) (year, lastWeeks) else (year, wholeWeeks)}
  val yearsAndWeeks = yearsAndWeeksZip.flatMap{case (year, weeks) => weeks.map(week => year.toString + "-" + "%02d".format(week))}

  yearsAndWeeks.toList
}
```

You can use `format` to properly show a number likewise:

```
scala> "%02d".format(4)
res15: String = 04

scala> "%02d".format(50)
res16: String = 50
```

On the REPL:

```
scala> weeksGenerator("2017-10", "2018-01")
res3: List[String] = List(2017-10, 2017-11, 2017-12, 2017-13, 2017-14, 2017-15, 2017-16, 2017-17, 2017-18, 2017-19, 2017-20, 2017-21, 2017-22, 2017-23, 2017-24, 2017-25, 2017-26, 2017-27, 2017-28, 2017-29, 2017-30, 2017-31, 2017-32, 2017-33, 2017-34, 2017-35, 2017-36, 2017-37, 2017-38, 2017-39, 2017-40, 2017-41, 2017-42, 2017-43, 2017-44, 2017-45, 2017-46, 2017-47, 2017-48, 2017-49, 2017-50, 2017-51, 2017-52, 2018-01)
```

I think this solution portrays a concise and clear way of using high order functions to approach this problem. It could be shortened, but I guess it will lose clearness.

Comment: Nice effort. But the solution will not work because of deviations between week based calendar and Gregorian calendar. To put it more consicely-
 A year does not have 52 weeks. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to rely on the java.time api

The code could look like this (I don't include the parsing of the input):

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.temporal.IsoFields
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters

val initialDate = LocalDate.ofYearDay(2017, 50).`with`(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR, 50).`with`(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY))
val finalDate = LocalDate.ofYearDay(2017, 50).`with`(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR, 8).`with`(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY))

for {
  i <- 0 to ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between(initialDate, finalDate).toInt
} yield initialDate.plusWeeks(i).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-ww"))
```

Here you have a [demo](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/jSNYEFm1QLaEviP2wgcNEA)

Comment: How about modifying the solution little bit to use an appropriate DateTimeFormatter to better match the question requirement?

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage the java time API to do the hard work for you (handling of leap week etc). Just parse your inputs into `LocalDate`, then use Chrono API to get the number of weeks in between.

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

def listOfWeeks(initialWeekString: String, finalWeekString: String): List[String] = {
  val dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-ww-EEE")
  val dateTimeFormatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-ww")

  val initialDate = LocalDate.parse(initialWeekString + "-Mon", dateTimeFormatter)
  val finalDate = LocalDate.parse(finalWeekString + "-Mon", dateTimeFormatter)

  val weeksCount = ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between(initialDate, finalDate).toInt

  (0 to weeksCount)
    .map(i => initialDate.plusWeeks(i).format(dateTimeFormatter2))
    .toList
}

println(listOfWeeks("2017-05", "2017-06"))

// List(2017-05, 2017-06)
```